# How do you change your icon

Tags: support, profile-page

Please tell me how to do this because it is important to me...?!?!.?!?.

Answer (score 4):

If by 'icon' you mean avatar, then you simply need to go to ['Edit Profile & Settings'](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) and click on 'Change picture', and then on the orange 'Upload a new picture' button.

[image]

Keep in mind that the standard limitations for uploading images to Stack apply - maximum size is 2 MB, and the image should be suitable for work. It should also be square, otherwise the aspect ratio might get mangled and distort the picture.